# It is required to have a mac to build iphone application or we can use VirtualBox to emulate the MAC OS X platform?

Tags: development

It is required to have a mac to build iphone application or we can use VirtualBox to emulate the MAC OS X platform and do the same task ? Is there any license restriction ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is required that you be running OS X and you can't virtualize OS X on non-Apple hardware (by terms in the EULA, not for any technical reasons). Therefore it follows that you need a Mac computer to build iPhone software.

See this question and answer for a discussion on virtualizing OS X: [Is there a way to evaluate OS X without purchasing Macintosh hardware?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/9876/is-there-a-way-to-evaluate-osx-without-purchasing-macintosh-hardware/9877#9877)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you would have to use a Mac computer.

Running MacOSX as a virtual machine would be against Apple's licensing terms.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to comply with all Apple's license restrictions, then, yes, you need a Mac to build and sign iOS apps using Apple's latest SDK tools.