# How to get Mac OS X to run in a VM on Windows

Tags: windows, vmware, virtualization, virtualbox

I want to be able to run RubyMotion on Windows 7 computers.  But RubyMotion only runs on Mac OS X Lion.  So it seems like the only option is to run a virtual machine on the Windows 7 computers which run Mac OS X.

What's the best way to do this?  I assume I have to buy a copy of Mac OS X for each Windows 7 computer?

Comment: No, as far as I know OSX is only licensed to be run on a Macintosh computer. If you need Windows the only option then is: Virtualize OSX in Windows which you install via Bootcamp on a Mac. Also see **[this answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/9877/13414)**. The accepted answer is even more strict. Apparently you can only virtualize OSX server?!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can technically run Lion in a VM, but I really really really wouldn't recommend it. Here's why:

1. You're basically entering the murky world of [Hackintoshes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSx86)
2. Hackintoshes are inherently "hacky". The performance is rarely going to be as reliable as running OSX on mac hardware.
3. You're violating Apple's EULA.

If you really want to do it, here's a [link](http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2011/09/how-to-install-fully-functional-mac-os-x-lion-virtual-machine-inside-windows-7/), but I really think it's a fool's game.

### Recommendation

You'd be better off just getting a Mac Mini or something and if you really want to run Windows natively, ***then remote desktop from Windows to your Mac mini***. I'd recommend that.

Comment: remote desktopping might be the best answer...

Comment: Even lion only allows the vm if the physical host is a Mac.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do have both OS X and Windows running on the same computer is to buy a Mac and run a Windows 7 VM on it using VMware Fusion.

Apple sees itself as a hardware company and uses its software to get you to buy their hardware.  As such, Apple is very committed to preventing anything that would allow you to use their software without buying their hardware and they are doing a pretty good job of it. If you're going to be developing for iOS (whether you use RubyMotion or not), then you are into a professional realm where time = money and the money you save by not buying a Mac will be eaten up by jumping through hoops trying to circumvent Apple's enforcement measures.