# How to install Mac OS X as a guest OS in VMware Workstation 8 (running in Ubuntu host)?

Tags: macos, vmware

How to install Mac OS X as a guest OS in VMware Workstation 8 (running in Ubuntu host)?

The author of this [askubuntu question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/70177/unity-vmware-workstation-and-the-super-windows-key) (in the question) claims to have done it, but doesn't say exactly how.  Haven't yet succeeded, tried various procedures (also with Virtualbox with no success) to get Mac OS X guest OS to run on VMware-Ubuntu host.

- Example unsuccessful procedure: boot-from-installable-USB procedure based upon a [install-Lion-USB-drive creation procedure](http://osxdaily.com/2011/07/08/make-a-bootable-mac-os-x-10-7-lion-installer-from-a-usb-flash-drive/) and then employing the [Plop boot manager in VMware](http://helpdeskgeek.com/how-to/boot-from-a-usb-flash-drive-in-vmware-workstation-7-1/).  Results in 'boot0: error' and hang of the guest machine.
- Next unsuccessful procedure: same as above but using http://kakewalk.se.  However, the guest OS did boot off of the kakewalk USB stick, but the boot-up "crashed" (possibly because of "unsupported motherboard" or some such).

Comment: This additional [askubuntu question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/77886/how-to-unlock-vmware-for-use-with-mac-os-x-guests-enable-mac-os-x-virtual-machi) might also be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not legally install OS X on VMware Workstation or Virtualbox and VMware has checks to prevent it.  You have to hack it to get it to work and we don't provide hacks here.

You can read more about it [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/51846/21703).

Comment: You are not a lawyer and this is a totally irrelevant answer.

Answer (score 0):

What about running Ubuntu as the host OS on Mac hardware (e.g. MacBook Pro), and running OS X as a guest OS?  This would not violate the Apple EULA.

Comment: This is not true. It would violate the Apple EULA. The EULA states that running OS X inside a VM is only allowed on Apple hardware running OS X as the host OS.